# Sistema de rotas em php

Tags: php

A minha estrutura atual é a seguinte :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço pra carregar o conteúdo na index quando a pessoa clicar no título sem que abra em outra página ( ou seja só troque o conteúdo central ), pesquisei sobre mas só encontrei coisas sobre frame works mvc e dicas pra fazer do jeito mais simples e adicionar o topo e footer do site nas outras páginas e linkar como realizado na imagem anterior, alguém teria conteúdo ou explicação pra me ajudar ?

Comment: Tu queres que se abra na mesma pagina? Não omporta que link seja e ele nunca, jamais sairá do index mais terá tudo que precisa?

Comment: Não sei se atende mas no conteúdo da index você pode carregar de acordo com o valor do parâmetro obtido via get colocado nos links. Dai faz if else ou case e require conteudoXXX

Comment: Procure por `ajaxify jQuery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você está querendo, ao meu ver, poderia ser resolvido tranquilamente com a utilização de um `include` dinâmico.

Você pode fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
<?php include 'topo.php'; ?>

 <?php 
        $pagina = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pagina');
        // faça um tratamento em "pagina" pra evitar qualquer ataque malicioso
        include 'paginas/' . $pagina '.php';    
 ?>    
<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Tendo em vista  a estrutura acima, você poderia simplesmente carregar uma página, criar links assim:

```
 http://meusite.com.br/?pagina=home
 http://meusite.com.br/?pagina=sobre
 http://meusite.com.br/?pagina=contato
```

Por padrão, se quiser carregar "home" sem nada ter sido passado, você pode fazer essa pequena alteração:

```
$pagina = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pagina') ?: 'home';
```

Há também outras formas legais de fazer isso, que é utilizando o framework Javascript Angular JS.

Se você usar o [NgRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute), pode ser uma boa solução para carregamento dinâmico de páginas.